# Django: Why is my custom save_model not working?

Tags: python, django

This is my save_model:

```
    # define the save model
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    # buchung is the initial value and obj the changed value

    # check if Buchung was added or changed
    if change == True:

        # get the objects
        buchung = Buchung.objects.get(buchung_id = obj.buchung_id)

        # calculate the change of the buchung_amount
        amountChange = obj.buchung_amount - buchung.buchung_amount

        # check if sollKonto has changed
        if obj.buchung_sollKonto_id != buchung.buchung_sollKonto_id:

            # check which type the initial konto is and reverse the buchung
            sollKonto_initial = Konto.objects.get(konto_id = buchung.buchung_sollKonto_id)

            if sollKonto_initial.konto_type == 'A':
                sollKonto_initial.konto_sum = sollKonto_initial.konto_sum - buchung.buchung_amount
            else:
                sollKonto_initial.konto_sum = sollKonto_initial.konto_sum + buchung.buchung_amount

            # save the object
            sollKonto_initial.save()

            # check which type the new konto is and do the buchung
            sollKonto = Konto.objects.get(konto_id = obj.buchung_sollKonto_id)
            if sollKonto.konto_type == 'A':
                sollKonto.konto_sum = sollKonto.konto_sum + obj.buchung_amount
            else:
                sollKonto.konto_sum = sollKonto.konto_sum - obj.buchung_amount

            # save the object
            sollKonto.save()


        # check if habenKonto has changed
        if obj.buchung_habenKonto_id != buchung.buchung_habenKonto_id:

            # check which type the initial konto is and reverse the buchung
            habenKonto_initial = Konto.objects.get(konto_id = buchung.buchung_habenKonto_id)

            if habenKonto_initial.konto_type == 'P':
                habenKonto_initial.konto_sum = habenKonto_initial.konto_sum - buchung.buchung_amount
            else:
                habenKonto_initial.konto_sum = habenKonto_initial.konto_sum + buchung.buchung_amount

            # save the object
            # !!! this line below is what doesn't seem to work !!!
            habenKonto_initial.save()

            # check which type the new konto is and do the buchung
            habenKonto = Konto.objects.get(konto_id = obj.buchung_habenKonto_id)
            if habenKonto.konto_type == 'P':
                habenKonto.konto_sum = habenKonto.konto_sum + obj.buchung_amount
            else:
                habenKonto.konto_sum = habenKonto.konto_sum - obj.buchung_amount

            # save the object
            habenKonto.save()

        # check if buchung_amount has changed
        if amountChange != 0:
            if obj.buchung_sollKonto_id == buchung.buchung_sollKonto_id:
                if sollKonto.konto_type == 'A':
                    sollKonto.konto_sum = sollKonto.konto_sum + amountChange
                else:
                    sollKonto.konto_sum = sollKonto.konto_sum - amountChange
            if obj.buchung_habenKonto_id == buchung.buchung_habenKonto_id:
                if habenKonto.konto_type == 'P':
                    habenKonto.konto_sum = habenKonto.konto_sum + amountChange
                else:
                    habenKonto.konto_sum = habenKonto.konto_sum - amountChange



    # no change, new one added
    else:
        sollKonto = Konto.objects.get(konto_id = obj.buchung_sollKonto_id)
        habenKonto = Konto.objects.get(konto_id = obj.buchung_habenKonto_id)
        if sollKonto.konto_type == 'A':
            sollKonto.konto_sum = sollKonto.konto_sum + obj.buchung_amount
        else:
            sollKonto.konto_sum = sollKonto.konto_sum - obj.buchung_amount
        if habenKonto.konto_type == 'P':
            habenKonto.konto_sum = habenKonto.konto_sum + obj.buchung_amount
        else:
            habenKonto.konto_sum = habenKonto.konto_sum - obj.buchung_amount

    # save the objects
    sollKonto.save()
    habenKonto.save()
    obj.save()
```

All values but the `habenKonto_initial` are changed & saved. I have tried many different things but I don't seem to get it to work. Please not that the 'sollKonto' , 'habenKonto', 'sollKonto_initial' & ' habenKonto_initial' are manyToManyFields in the 'buchung'.

My models are as following:

```
class Konto(models.Model):
    konto_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    konto_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) #actually AutoField is safer
    konto_anfangsBestand = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    konto_sum = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    konto_types = (
        ('A', 'Aktiv'),
        ('P', 'Passiv')
    )
    konto_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=konto_types)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.konto_title


class Buchung(models.Model):
    buchung_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    buchung_descr = models.CharField('Description', max_length=128)
    buchung_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    buchung_sollKonto = models.ForeignKey(Konto, related_name='sollKonto')
    buchung_habenKonto = models.ForeignKey(Konto, related_name='habenKonto')
    buchung_date = models.DateTimeField('Buchungsdatum')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.buchung_descr
```

Comment: you know that `save_model()` is only called if you save model thru admin, right?

Comment: you dont need ``buchung = Buchung.objects.get(buchung_id = obj.buchung_id)``. this is equal to ``obj``.

Comment: @doniyor yes, I know :)

Comment: @doniyor actually there's a difference because the 'buchung' has the initial values and 'obj' has the new (changed) ones.

Comment: if ``change=True``, then ``form`` has all changed fields, otherwise ``obj`` is either the new or unchanged version. ``obj`` wont have changes in it. am i correct?

Comment: I don't think so, if that would be the case this statement:
`if obj.buchung_sollKonto_id != buchung.buchung_sollKonto_id:`
would never be true, but it is.

Comment: on the contrary. you are fetching the object with its own id, of course it is always true. in your case ``obj=buchung``

Comment: It's only true when `buchung_sollKonto_id` changes. Then the `obj` contains the new values and the `buchung` the old ones

Comment: ``obj`` cannot contain new values before the ``obj`` is saved. you are in a state now where ``obj`` isnot saved yet. you are taking the responsibility to save it by overriding ``save_model()``

Comment: `obj` does contain the new values and I do save the `obj` with `obj.save()`
The thing is I want to change the related models (sollKonto, sollKonto_initial etc.) as well. That's where the problem is..

Comment: you save it at the end of ``save_model()``.

Comment: yes, do you think that's the problem?

Comment: Why are you firing ORM calls for objects you already have in `save_model` ?

Comment: @Brandon which ones? I am new to django so I might have missed something

Comment: I should clarify: every change in the buchung has effect on the related konto, so if a buchung is changed I need to reverse the (old) effect and redo the new effect it has on the konto's

Comment: Brandon means ``buchung = Buchung.objects.get(buchung_id = obj.buchung_id)`` which i meant earlier

Comment: There are several things wrong with the save_model method... `if change == True` can be just `if change`. `buchung = Buchung.objects.get(buchung_id = obj.buchung_id)` is completely unecessary if this method is in the `save_model` for `BuchungAdmin`. It is already available as `obj`

Comment: Any time you have a ForeginKey relationship on a Django model, you already have the object. You don't have to go look it up by ID. Example: `obj.buchung_sollKonto` will give you the `Konto` object

Comment: You can also drop the `AutoFields`. Unless you specify a primary key field on your model, the AutoField `id` will be added to your model automatically. It's just extra work you don't need to do.

Comment: Thanks for helping me guys! But how can this statement be true sometimes if buchung is the same as obj?  ' if obj.buchung_sollKonto_id != buchung.buchung_sollKonto_id: '

Comment: it is always true, not sometimes. because you are fetching the same object from db with its own ID and comparing its ``buchung_sollKonto_id`` with its own ``buchung_sollKonto_id``.

Comment: @doniyor you mean it should always be false? It actually isn't, I've put a print function to see whether it's true or false and when the 'buchung_sollKonto' is changed it prints true and if not it doesn't. So I can guarantee you it's not always false :S